# What type of statistic test should i run to examine learning effects for one indivduall with only pass/fail as data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I have done a experiment where one individuall have done repetead trials in a pass/fail situation. I was wondering what kind of test should i do to determine if there is a increase in performance? There is 20 data points. I was thinking about treating first half of trials with second half of the trials and look if they can be assumed to be from the same population.

Comment: A linear (logistic) model, probably accounting for the correlation. Can you post your data in the question?

Comment: Thank you for the help very kind! Unfortunatly i can not upload the data.